# AttributeError: can't set attribute in qiskit Grover Algorithm

Tags: qiskit

Here is my code

```py
def gen_grover(width):
    oracle = QuantumCircuit(width, name='q') 
    oracle.z(width-1)
    full_circuit = GroverOperator(oracle, insert_barriers=False, name='q')
    full_circuit = dag_to_circuit(circuit_to_dag(full_circuit))
    full_circuit.qregs[0].name = 'q'
    full_circuit = full_circuit.decompose()
    full_circuit = transpile(full_circuit,optimization_level=3) 
    return full_circuit
```

I get the error below:

`full_circuit.qregs[0].name = 'q' AttributeError: can't set attribute python-BaseException`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? GroverOperator creates the circuit with registers with foxed names. If you want to assign custom names to the register, you have to build the circuit yourself.

Comment: how to assign custom name

Comment: _how to assign custom name_ To what and why?

Comment: full_circuit.qregs[0].name = 'q'  here i get error how to change it

Comment: Again. You cannot change the name of a register, when the register is created automatically for you (here by using `GroverOperator`). You can name registers, when you create them manually.. So, WHY do you want to change the name of that register?

Answer (score 0):

Register `name` [is a read-only property](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/13e748a1de451d74d47daef727ffe278561d1df5/qiskit/circuit/register.py#L143-L146) (getter). There is no setter.

See also https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumRegister.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumRegister subclass which shows `name` Attribute

Comment: Then how to set the name